# How to Integrate Custom C++ Module into Custom Version of NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, embedded-v8

I wish to create an executable that uses NodeJS to run a specific JavaScript file. However, this NodeJS should have additional "modules" added that expose C++ classes/functions to the JavaScript scope using `require`.

So far, I have successfully compiled NodeJS to a library, and have linked it to my super simple C++ program:

```cpp
#include <vector>

#include "node.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<char*> newArgs;

    newArgs.push_back(argv[0]);

    char file[] = "my_file.js";
    newArgs.push_back(file);

    return node::Start(2, &newArgs[0]);
}
```

As you can tell, this simply executes the JavaScript file named "my_file.js" within the same directory of the executable.

Now the question is, how could I expose potential C++ classes/functions that I create in this code to the JavaScript?

---

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "node.h"

class Weather {
public:
    Weather() {}
    void makeItRain() {
        std::cout << "It is raining\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<char*> newArgs;

    newArgs.push_back(argv[0]);

    char file[] = "my_file.js";
    newArgs.push_back(file);

    // hypothetical code
    node::AddClass(Weather, "weather");

    return node::Start(2, &newArgs[0]);
}
```

---

```
// my_file.js
var Weather = require("weather");
var w = new Weather();
w.makeItRain();
```

---

Any suggestions?
The closest thing I've found is [v8pp](https://github.com/pmed/v8pp), but I don't know how to receive an instance of a v8::Isolate.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking about is called an "addon", and there is a lot of official documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

It's not quite as easy as the hypothetical code in your question, but the basic principle is the same. A bit more code is required to bridge the worlds of C++ and JavaScript (keep in mind that one of them is garbage-collected while the other does manual memory management; and one is compiled ahead of time while the other is shipped as source).

Do note the section on "N-API". By default, you will be programming against V8's C++ API, which sometimes changes between versions. To make your addons compatible with as many Node/V8 versions as possible, N-API provides an abstraction layer that is designed to be stable over time.